# Simplify into a loop

Tags: for-loop, stata

I'm having some difficulty simplifying something into a closed loop. I'm trying to calculate the mean, median, max, min and standard deviation of 6 different variables during 7 years for 213 countries.

I would like to know if there is a way to create a loop to calculate the mean,median,etc.. for each variable.

This is what I have until now.

```
forvalues x=1/213 {
use Base_T03.dta, clear
egen trend=fill(1/1491)
drop if trend <7*(`x'-1)+1 | trend > 7*(`x')

gen str variable=""
replace variable="consumption_growth" in 1
replace variable="gov_expo_growth" in 2
replace variable="exports_growth" in 3
replace variable="imports_growth" in 4
replace variable="gdp_growth" in 5
replace variable="population_growth" in 6

egen m1= mean (consumption_growth)
egen m2= mean (gov_expo_growth)
egen m3= mean (exports_growth)
egen m4= mean (imports_growth)
egen m5= mean (gdp_growth)
egen m6= mean (population_growth)

gen Mean = .
replace Mean=m1 in 1
replace Mean=m2 in 2
replace Mean=m3 in 3
replace Mean=m4 in 4
replace Mean=m5 in 5
replace Mean=m6 in 6

drop m*

egen m1= median (consumption_growth)
egen m2= median (gov_expo_growth)
egen m3= median (exports_growth)
egen m4= median (imports_growth)
egen m5= median (gdp_growth)
egen m6= median (population_growth)

gen Median = .
replace Median=m1 in 1
replace Median=m2 in 2
replace Median=m3 in 3
replace Median=m4 in 4
replace Median=m5 in 5
replace Median=m6 in 6

drop m*

egen m1= max (consumption_growth)
egen m2= max (gov_expo_growth)
egen m3= max (exports_growth)
egen m4= max (imports_growth)
egen m5= max (gdp_growth)
egen m6= max (population_growth)

gen Max = .
replace Max=m1 in 1
replace Max=m2 in 2
replace Max=m3 in 3
replace Max=m4 in 4
replace Max=m5 in 5
replace Max=m6 in 6

drop m*

egen m1= min (consumption_growth)
egen m2= min (gov_expo_growth)
egen m3= min (exports_growth)
egen m4= min (imports_growth)
egen m5= min (gdp_growth)
egen m6= min (population_growth)

gen Min = .
replace Min=m1 in 1
replace Min=m2 in 2
replace Min=m3 in 3
replace Min=m4 in 4
replace Min=m5 in 5
replace Min=m6 in 6

drop m*

egen m1= sd (consumption_growth)
egen m2= sd (gov_expo_growth)
egen m3= sd (exports_growth)
egen m4= sd (imports_growth)
egen m5= sd (gdp_growth)
egen m6= sd (population_growth)

gen Desvest = .
replace Desvest=m1 in 1
replace Desvest=m2 in 2
replace Desvest=m3 in 3
replace Desvest=m4 in 4
replace Desvest=m5 in 5
replace Desvest=m6 in 6

drop m* trend
drop if variable==""
drop consumption* gov_expo* exports* imports* gdp* population* year
save Tabla_`x'.dta, replace
}
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Remember to please [give appropriate feedback](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to the answers you receive. You still have noticeable feedback pending at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007457/a-new-chart-every-sheet.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop here, as you don't need one in many contexts you would, with a different language.

Have you tried `collapse`:

```
clear
set more off

input ///
country time gdp popul
1 1 63 29
1 2 68 30
1 3 69 34
2 1 88 40
2 2 87 43
2 3 87 45
end

*-----

collapse (mean) mgdp=gdp mpop=popul (median) medgdp=gdp medpop=popul, by(country)

format %9.2f *gdp *pop
list, noobs
```

?

It's best you take an early, serious read of the [User's Guide](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/u.pdf). This will save you major headaches going forward with Stata.